# When using Object.assign, why only the inner object properties of copied object are changed, when changing the original object?

Tags: javascript, shallow-copy

I'm doing a shallow copy and trying to understand why only the inner objects properties are changed, given the fact that a shallow copy copies the reference from, lets say car into copiedCar, so if I change a property on the car object, shouldn't that property also change on the copiedCar object?

```js
const car = {
  name: "Audi",
  properties: {
    color: "yellow",
    wheels: 19
  }
}

const copiedCar = Object.assign({}, car);

car.name = "BMW",
car.properties.color = "Green"
car.properties.wheels = 15

console.log(copiedCar)

//Here it will print: 
//{
//   name:"Audi",
//   properties: {
//    color:"Green",
//    wheels:15
//  }
//}
```

Why are only the properties of inner object changed and not also the property of the object?

Comment: Because that’s what it means to create a shallow copy. `Object.assign({}, car)` creates a shallow copy of `car`, but not of `car.properties`. `car.properties` and `copiedCar.properties` still point to the same object.

Comment: So Object.assign creates a shallow copy of an object, but the properties of the shallow copy object don't point to the same address memory as the as the original object properties, only if that property is an inner object?

Comment: If i do this, for example: const copiedCar = car, then, all the properties will be changed, including the name property of the copied object, and this is also shallow copy

Comment: My question would be, what's the difference between Object.assign({}, car) and const copiedCar = car, given that both of them create a shallow copy, but the results are different

Comment: No, `copiedCar = car` does not create a copy. In fact, it doesn't "create" anything, it just gives the 'car' object another name.